# How to replace string replace ending with a . (period)?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace the string `rs.` from my string

```
df['Purpose'] = df['Purpose'].str.replace('rs.','')

+-------+----------+--------+
| Input | Expected | Output |
+-------+----------+--------+
| rs.22 | 22       | 22     |
+-------+----------+--------+
| rs32  | rs32     | 2      |
+-------+----------+--------+
```

The code for testing:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(['rs.22', 'rs32'], columns=['Purpose'])
x['Purpose'] = x['Purpose'].str.replace('rs.','')
print('x mod', x)
```

This gives the following output:

```
x mod   Purpose
   0      22
   1       2
```

PS: extracting numbers only method using the regex `[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?` couldn't distinguish between rs.3.5 as 3.5 but gave the output as .3.5

Comment: Try `df['Purpose'] = df['Purpose'].str.replace('rs.', '', regex=False)`. The `regex` parameter defaults to `True`, but it looks like you just want regular Python-style string replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) operates in regex mode. You have two simple options to get around it. The preferred one, suggested by [@101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335009/how-to-replace-string-replace-ending-with-a-period#comment89645218_51335009), is to turn off regex:

```
df['Purpose'] = df['Purpose'].str.replace('rs.', '', regex=False)
```

Another alternative is to escape the dot so it matches an actual period instead of any character. This is the option to use in versions of pandas before 0.23.0, when the `regex` parameter was introduced:

```
df['Purpose'] = df['Purpose'].str.replace(r'rs\.', '')
```

Regex matching is generally slower than simple string comparisons, so the first option can be expected to be more performant.

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'` error for the regex. The 2nd one worked

Comment: version is 0.21.1

Comment: @suku. That's why I've shown a couple of alternatives. If there was ever a version that didn't use regex, OP's original version should work.

Comment: @suku Your pandas version does not have the regex flag: see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html, therefore, use the alternative answer if you can't update.

Comment: @suku. Docs say:New in version 0.23.0.

Comment: yes. but according to this discussion it was to be enabled in 0.13 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4555. Anyway I will update mine to the latest version . Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 3):

In regex, the period '`.`' matches almost all characters. To match a literal period, escape it with a preceding backslash:

```
x['Purpose'] = x['Purpose'].str.replace('rs\.','')
```

See the regex howto: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one, you need to use st replace pandas has its own replace function:-

```
    >>> df
       Input
    0  rs.22
    1  rs321
   >>> df['Input'].replace("rs\.","",regex=True)
    0       22
    1    rs321
    Name: Input, dtype: object
   >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is that [`pandas.Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by default has `regex=True`, so it assumes the passed-in pattern is a regular expression.

You can use:

```
x['Purpose'] = x['Purpose'].str.replace('rs.', '', regex=False)
```